# How to separate user-defined messages for different databases

Tags: sql-server, error-handling

I have 2 databases, each of them has its own user-defined messages. The problem is that their message_id's stored in sys.messages intersect so these DB's cannot be deployed on the same SQL Server instance without changing all messages in one database (but these is too expensive - I have to change ALL stored procedures).

Is there any way to make error messages specific to database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sys.message table is database-wide so you simply cannot do that easily. That table really should only be used for things that are DB-wide (like extended stored procedures and other server extensions), not for stored procedure. But I guess changing that is already too late.

I see only two ways around it:

1. Use the "language" field when adding the message to identify not the message but the application. Of course, that will cause additional problems as you'll need to have each application use it's own "language".
2. Use two different instances of SQL server, one for each app.